# What is the utility of squared radius and inverse squared radius for lighting computations?

Tags: lighting

On one of the slides from "DirectX 11 Rendering in Battlefield 3" PowerPoint I noticed the folowing code:

```
struct Light {
    float3 pos; float sqrRadius;
    float3 color; float invSqrRadius;
}
```

I don't understand why would they store the squared radius and even the inverse squared (which I believe is simply 1-squared radius) instead of simply storing the radius? How are they using this data in their computations? Moreover, what about cone and line lights? This struct must be only for the point lights, I can't see it working for other types - there is not enought data. Still I would love to know how they use that square and invSquare.

**UPDATE:** Ok I finally got it.

Here is the classic light attenuation equation, easily found on the net:

```
float3 lightVector = lightPosition - surfacePosition;

float attenuation = saturate(1 - length(lightVector)/lightRadius);
```

It is relatively costly as `length(lightVector)` is actually doing this:

```
length(lightVector) = sqrt(dot(lightVector, lightVector);
```

moreover division operation `(/lightRadius)` is also quite costly.

Instead of computing light attenuation this way, you can compute it the following way, which would be much faster:

```
attenuation = saturate(1 - dot(lightVector, lightVector)*invRadiusSqr);
```

where invRadiusSqr can be pre-computed at CPU level and passed as a shader constant.

Moreover, you get a quadratic light attenuation as a result (instead of linear in the former case), which is even better, as IRL light has shown to have quadratic falloff.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Padding. Shaders are 16bytes aligned. And if you take a look at how the code is formated, you will see that it will get packed into two float4. Why not store something usefull when you will get it from free from the cache?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is simply a kind of optimization given that `invSqrRadius = 1/SqrRadius`, instead of calculating the inverse squared radius for each light every time they simply cache it, the reason is that division is usually a "slow" operation at least when compared to multiplication.

This optimization is relevant especially:

- when the operation is done a huge amount of times for each light, so
  caching the value will free extra CPU/GPU cycles
- And assuming the memory access time for reading the value is actually
  faster than recalculating it.

Regarding how it is used, I am not sure about their specific implementation, but regarding `1/sqrRadius`, this is simply used for light attenuation, falloff and culling. It's also relevant for directional and spotlight, the only difference in case of spotlight is that you need to calculate the spotlight factor *after* [applying the attenuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Regarding directional lights like sun, it usually doesn't have any attenuation or falloff, so I would guess it will be ignored.

[EDIT]
Just to elaborate more, it is *not* irrelevant data. The light Irradiance can be calculated using the following equation:

> **E** = Phi / 4*pi* rSqr;
>
> Where
>
> **E** is the area density of flux.
>
> **Phi** is radiance flux.
>
> **4*pi*rSqr** is the surface area of a sphere.

This equation explains why the amount of energy received falls off with the squared distance.

Another point is you need to calculate distance between the vertex and the light to calculate the light contribution on a specific vertex (this value is unlikely to be cached), the vertex can be in or out the light range which brings us to the next point where `Radius Square` is useful for culling.

If you want a practical example for calculating light falloff and culling, this is especially useful in tiled based deferred renderers, [here is one example](http://graphicrants.blogspot.com/2012/04/tiled-light-culling.html).

Comment: Curses, you beat me by 7 seconds!  ;)  (and with a more comprehensive answer, too!)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment, esp for the link! From what I understood from the latter link, Battlefield 3 stores not the radius but the actual distance between the light source and the light receiver, right? That's the "d" value they use in the article.

Comment: @cubrman it's hard to speculate without seeing code. My guess is that it is the inverse radiusSqr. And the equations they use might greatly vary from the article.

Comment: But tell me, how can you use a bare inverted light radius squared in a lighting calculation? Every source I found on the net tells me that I need to find the DISTANCE between the receiving surface and the light source, divide the latter by the original light radius AND THEN square the result. Where would you ever use squared radius or invSqrRadius? That seems like completely irrelevant data to me.

Comment: @cubrman updated the answer.

Comment: Also computing the inverse square root is magically fast : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: @njzk2 this is an approximation, it isn't as good as precomputing and caching the value and definitely not as fast as multiplication (or even division).

Comment: I does very few operations. About 4 multiplications, so in the same order of magnitude. Also it is used for light effects, and has a imprecision of ~3%. For changing values that you can't cache, every one uses that since quake3.

Comment: @cubman : when you have a squared distance.

Comment: @njzk2 yes I agree it's widely used for changing values. Not useful when you can easily cache the value.

Comment: I am still struggling. Can you actually use the area density of flux as attenuation? I tried simply substituting my classic attenuation formula with this one but it produces completely flat lighting across the entire light mesh. How would you use this light irradiance value in lighting calculation?

Comment: @cubrman You usually don't use irradiance directly unless you are implementing a physically based renderer. My point was to show how the attenuation was derived. You are more likely to use invSqr for culling and falloff

Comment: @concept3d I am sorry for annoying you, but can you elaborate more? What do you mean "how the attenuation was derived"? I still can't see how squared radius can be useful. Could you provide a link?

Comment: @cubrman I already did. If you are very concerned about invSqrRad and attenuation. it's used for two reasons in the bf3 ppt. 1st for culling and 2nd for light falloff, as I said in my answer if you want the light contribution per vertex you need the distance to that vertex, if you are calculating physical quantities, or need light culling/falloff you need invSqrRadius. it's not directly used to calculate light contribution on a specific vertex.

Comment: @concept3d ok so it's ONLY for culling, now I got it.

Comment: @cubrman and light falloff. Also I mentioned where the quadratic attenuation formula originated; from the irradiance flux equation.

Answer (score 6):

invSqrRadius isn't 1 - sqrRadius;  it's 1 / sqrRadius.

It means that you can multiply by invSqrRadius, instead of dividing by sqrRadius (as division is typically much more expensive than multiplication)

Answer (score 6):

The other answers here dealt with the inverse square radius, but I'm going to look at the squared radius instead (which concept3d touched on, but I believe it merits further discussion).

What squares are useful for is distance comparisons.  We know that calculating the distance between two points involves a square root, and square roots are expensive to calculate, but if all we want to do is *compare distances* (in order to find which is less or greater, and do something interesting based on the result) we can throw out the square root.

If sqrt(x) > sqrt(y) then it's also the case that x > y.

For a light, the squared radius is the same as the distance between the light's center and it's maximum extent - squared, of course.

For lighting computations this can be used for an early-out case.  If the distance between the point you're lighting and the light's center (squared) is greater than the squared radius, the point recieves no light and you don't need to run the rest of your computations.  This is therefore just an optimization (a fairly common one) - we can use squared radius to do the distance comparison without expensive square roots, and at a cost of just a subtraction and dot product.

I, of course, don't know if this is *exactly* what BF3 is using it for, but I would expect that I'm not too far off the mark.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, the code will be: if (dot((lightPos - surfacePos), (lightPos - surfacePos)) > lightRadiusSqr) don't do lighting, right?